# Context API Crashes the app when i use <APpProvider> <APP> </APpProvider>

Tags: reactjs

[When ever i put
 `<AppProvider> <App/> </AppProvider>`
the app just crashes , pages becomes blank , event there is no error or warning regarding this

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb3dT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St3MC.png)

after putting the  syntex the app just crashes , m using react 18
code :
`<AppProvider> <APP /> </AppProvider>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you wrote `childern` instead of `children` in your AppProvider component in AppContext.js file.

Fix this and you will be good to go.

Comment: thanks buddy i was stuck from 2 day and didn't noticed